# Flutter, AmplifyStorageS3 plugin not added correctly

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

[image]

getting

Error :

```
/*
dynamic AmplifyStorageS3()
package:my_budget_app/main.dart

AmplifyStorageS3 isn't a type.
Try correcting the name to match an existing type
*/
```

I am following this docs
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/flutter/#provision-backend-storage

Amplify storage S3 is not imported correctly.
I cleared cache and reinstalled all the pubs
I deleted publock file and pub get all the files no luck
I restarted vscode a couple of times no luck

I see the import says not used so AmplifyStorageS3 class is not exported from the package
ackage:amplify_storage_s3/amplify_storage_s3.dart ???

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 3 ideas.

1: In package import `import 'package:amplify_storage_s3/amplify_storage_s3.dart';` add "as ampl" to the end and then you will have something like this:

```
import 'package:amplify_storage_s3/amplify_storage_s3.dart' as ampl;
```

And then write:

```
ampl.AmplifyStorageS3 storage = ampl.AmplifyStorageS3();
```

2: Hold ctrl and left click on the imported package, find this class in the package and find out what's wrong.

3: Check your pubspec.yaml and so on for minimum requirements:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

[image]

Comment: Funny as it sounds. On your step 2. I went into the file and added export class AmplfyStroageS3 class. Then saved and did a restart. 
Still dint work then I removed the export, saved the file.
Vola! Worked. Something to do with library cache no clue nevertheless it worked

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to solve this problem! I would be grateful if you mark my post as a solution (tick).